# Swap buttons in layout

Tags: java, 2d, android, graphics, software-engineering

Say I have 4 buttons. I want to have button 2 always swap out with another button, randomly. 
So, when the user taps button 2, it should swap with another button (randomly).

Now, `button 2` is at the bottom right corner. So if the user taps button 2 again, it has the option to 
swap with the other three buttons. How can I achieve this?

I have already tried to make an array of the four values:

```
top_right, top_left, bottom_right, bottom_left
```

And have successfully had them swap, but it was very memory inefficient, and took a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a working demo using android's built-in buttons.

This is the main Activity class. Each button have the same onClick method buttonClicked().

```java
List<View> buttons = new ArrayList<View>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Store the button to the buttons array for later.
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.button));
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.button2));
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.button3));
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.button4));
}


public void buttonClicked(View v) {
    // Remove the clicked button from it's frame layout parent.
    ViewManager p = (ViewManager) v.getParent();
    p.removeView(v);

    // Find another button randomly.
    Random rng = new Random();
    View v2;
    do {
        int i = rng.nextInt(4);
        v2 = buttons.get(i);
    } while (v2 == v); // Loop until you get a different button to swap with.

    // Remove the other button from it's frame layout parent.
    ViewManager p2 = (ViewManager) v2.getParent();
    p2.removeView(v2);

    // Now simply insert each button into the other buttons frame layout.
    p.addView(v2, v2.getLayoutParams());
    p2.addView(v, v.getLayoutParams());
}
```

This is how the layout looks like. I have each button in a separate frame layout which stay where they are with the buttons inside swapping which frame container they are inside.

[image]

If anything is unclear just ask.

Comment: Also, in this line : `while (v2 == v);` when wil v2 == v?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused on how to put each frame layout into the gridLayout. Could you post the xml? Thanks. For me, when I try to put the frame layout in, there are many tiny grids to put it into. I have never worked with grid and frame layout, so I would really appreciate it if you also posted your xml. Again, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @RuchirBaronia `nextInt(4)` returns an int between 0-3. So it returns a number from 0 and up to but not including the number you passed in. Notice that `buttons` have all 4 buttons in it, so the indices goes from 0-3. This also means that when you pick a random button to swap with it might pick the one you clicked, and I guess you don't want the button to swap position with itself. So the v2 == v is needed to make sure it loops if this happens.

Comment: Ohhhh that makes so much more sense. Thanks! Do you mind posting the layout xml also? For some reason, when I try to put the frame layout in, the grid layout expands out of being 2x2. I don't know why...'

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Yeah, if you use grid layout can be a pain because the cells start out so small, at least for me. Here is the XML file you see on the image. https://gist.github.com/61f63e23f313b0d29a72

Comment: Alright. So when you made that xml file, did you just make it through the hard coded xml...or the layout drag-and-drop thing that android studio provide? Because it's like impossible to do through the drag and drop, how do you do it through that?

Comment: Also, although I understand the do-while loop, why would it even start? Why would it even start because in the beginning, v2 != v, so why would the code in the do execute? Thanks so much

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I just drag and dropped. I paid most attention to the numbers on top that said which row/column I was hovering over when putting the frame layouts into the grid layout. Also make sure that columnCount and rowCount in the grid layout are set to however many columns/rows you have when you are done as those don't change back if you accidentally put the object in the wrong cell. I still haven't used android's layout manager too much though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32176/discussion-between-ruchir-baronia-and-christer).

Comment: Hello Christer, for some reason, the buttons are still moving really slowly. I have moved most of the code of the on click listener into a separate thread to do the view deletion and creation in the background. For some reason, it's still really slow. This may be happening because I changed the buttons to image buttons. What should I do to make it faster? Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid. Find a way to do all these changes without causing invalidations to the layout. I think this happens every time you remove and add a button.

Comment: So where do you think I should do the removal and addition of the button? Should I put it in async task or something? If I can't do this faster, then is there some way that I can just change the image of the button, so that it looks as though the buttons have swapped? I don't know how I could achive that. If you don't mind, could you edit your answer and guide me how? For example, instead of manually moving and removing the views, just swap the properties of the views so that it looks as though the buttons have been swapped. I have been searching and researching how to make it faster for two

Comment: days now, and have also looked into things like aysnc task, and doing it in a background service. But, I don't think that will actually make it faster... There aren't many things online about this, so I'm stuck. Thanks so much, and I will really, really appreciate your edit. I am really lost at this point, because I don't know what to do to make this process faster. Thanks for your guidance. :)

Comment: First, I don't want to change my answer as it then wouldn't reflect your question, it should rather be its own question then. And it is http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112025/game-is-responding-very-slowly . Second, this is why you should consider using OpenGL ES directly or a library like libgdx. It gives more control over the graphics and better performance as the built-in gui isn't intended for frequent changes like this. You might be able to "hack" the built-in to do what you want efficiently, but my recommendation is to not use it for games. This is my last comment here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the solution you describe in your question, you can achieve it pretty easily with an `ArrayList`. This is assuming you have some sort of class for your buttons. If not, it might be a bit more cumbersome. The logic's the same though.

Create the initial list at the start of your class with the buttons:

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
buttons.add(new Button("button1", xPos, yPos));
buttons.add(new Button("button2", xPos, yPos));
buttons.add(new Button("button3", xPos, yPos));
buttons.add(new Button("button4", xPos, yPos));
```

Then whenever the user clicks on one of them, run this:

```
// Make this equal the button the user clicks!
Button userSelection = GetClickedButton();

// Remove that button from the array.
buttons.remove(userSelection);

// Select a random button from the remaining ones.
Button toSwap = buttons.get(new Random().nextInt(buttons.size())));                     

// Now swap. Just swap the positions of the chosen buttons.
SwapButtonPositions(userSelection, toSwap);

// Add the removed button back to the list. 
buttons.add(userSelection);
```

EDIT: I misread your question. I thought you wanted any button to be swappable, not just one of them. The logic for doing that is the same as above. Just have some way to tag the swappable button (like giving it a name) and run the code whenever it's clicked, rather than when any button's clicked.

Comment: Great answer! Are xPos and yPos in DP or pixels?

Comment: I had pixels in mind, to be honest. I forgot android uses DP. It doesn't really matter though. Just replace it with whatever co-ordinate system you're using :D

Comment: buttons.add(new Button("button1", 66, 177));

Comment: Would that work as a possible button object creation? It is giving me some errors

Comment: That should work to create a button, assuming your button class is setup to take those parameters. Unless you're using a built in button class?

Comment: I'm not sure then...Here is a screenshot of my error:

Comment: http://snag.gy/dVmJM.jpg

Comment: Ah, I see. You're using `android.widget.buttons`. That's a built in android class for buttons. My code was based on you having written your own simple button class. If you want to use `android.widget.buttons` then you'll need to look into constructing and/or positioning the widget buttons programmatically. That's not something I've done, so I can't be of any help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32138/discussion-between-ruchir-baronia-and-kevloughrey).