# Comparing the images

Tags: java, 2d, android, game-design, textures

I have a drawable, which I want to compare to. I created a drawable object with it, and when I log it with toString, I get:

```
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41f95548
```

I am randomly selecting a button, and I want to keep randomly selecting until the image of the image button is not `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41f95548` Now, I want to compare using this code:

```
do{
}while(buttonBackground = android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41f95548 ));
```

**buttonBackground is a drawable object.**

This, for some reason, gets me an error:

[image]

How can I compare images with a code like this `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41f95548`. What is this code called? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make it legal by saying

```
while(buttonBackground.toString().equals("android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41f95548"))
```

That's apples-to-apples. But it probably won't be doing what you intend.

A better way will be to remember which *index* you chose, and then compare the index til you get a different one. Something like

```
int currentIndex = <something, the current button image>...

    ...
    int newIndex = rng.nextInt(4)
} while(newIndex != currentIndex);
```

(By the way, Do you mean != or ==? Are you choosing randomly til you get a different one?)

Hope that helps a little!

Comment: Hey, so for the index thing...I wish I could do that, but I cant. See, my program is getting a random button and then swapping the properties of the two buttons. I was doing the index thing here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112025/game-is-responding-very-slowly But...it was too slow. I like your "apples to apples" method. Why did you mention it will probably not work? Thanks, I have liked, and will mark best answer once I get this!

Comment: Also...I meant ==. I wrote it wrong in my screen shot. I guess I should change it to `.equals` when trying your "apples to apples" method, right?

Comment: Hmm...I think I know why you were saying it wont work...That code is changing every time, which means it wont work some times? It is not constant. Why is that, isn't there only one image code? What is that code even called? Thanks so much

Comment: How should I compare the images now? I just don't want the image button that I pick from the array list to have that one image.